# Accessing script positional parameters inside a function

Tags: bash

Test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$1
function test {
echo "dollar1 $1"
echo "var $var"
}
test
exit
```

output

```
./test.sh d
dollar1
var d
```

Why isn't `$1` populated inside the function, and is there a way to pass `$1`...`$n` to all functions without having them defined as a variable separately?

Comment: As a sneaky hack, on Linux you can read your command-line arguments from `/proc/$$/cmdline` anywhere in your script (does not work on other platforms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function has its own arguments. You can pass all arguments to a function using `"$@"`, which expands to all the positional parameters in order:

```
test "$@"
```

Comment: Got it. Cheers. I knew it was something simple! (I'll accept it in 10 minutes, can't do so yet).